# how to handle memory management in Bradley, Fayyad and Reina algorithm

Tags: c, memory-management, cluster-analysis

I have to implement the BFR algorithm in C and one of the tasks is to handle memory: in the BFR algorithm we have to load a chunk of data (reading it from a file) that perfectly fits in main memory (I suppose RAM) and repeat the clustering process for each chunk. I'm here to ask which is the correct approach to this problem. How can I get the right amount of data that I can load in each iteration of the algorithm?

Comment: You are not going to get a chunk of data that “perfectly fits in main memory” on a multi-user general-purpose operating system. Memory use is dynamic; it changes from moment to moment and is mostly managed by the operating system. Making software work efficiently with the memory hierarchy involves a number of considerations, such as L1 cache size. But, looking at your earlier questions, it seems unlikely you are ready to deal with hardware concerns on this level. Pick a reasonable amount of memory to use, get your algorithm working, and worry about efficiency later.

Comment: I already implemented the algorithm, now I have to determinate the size of the chunk in each iteration